# printf to prevent segmentation fault in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The following is a part of a function.

```
l->length[l->cl] = atoi(p->wds[p->cw]);
printf("FD %d\n", l->length[l->cl]);
p->cw = p->cw + 1;
l->cl = l->cl + 1; 
printf("prevent from seg fault\n");
instr(p);
```

If I remove the `printf("prevent from seg fault\n");` I get segmentation fault, but if I keep it it runs and go to the nest function and so on.

So my question is just in general why does this happen, I know I am not showing enough of my code so you can see why the segmentation happen, but if there is any general explanation for this, I also had this in another place in my program but at the end I could remove it?

Regards Orri

Comment: There's probably undefined behaviour somewhere. A short, complete sample that demonstrates the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not a useful mental state to ask "how to prevent a segmentation fault". A segmentation fault is the result of a programming error, and it makes no sense to ask "how to prevent errors". You should instead ask "how to write XYZ correctly", and in fact you can even leave out the "correctly" since there's nothing else. So just "How do I use printf?".

Comment: My guess is overwritten memory in another part of your program. Remove the printf and start removing other stuff until the problem goes away. Then you can start narrowing down exactly where things go wrong.

Comment: Thanks all I am going to try to narrow it down like dutt suggest, and Kerrak I am not in useful mental state right now doing this assignment:=), but you are right. I will maybe come with more details if I can not figure this out, this is first time I am programming using linked list and so much struct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as the standard is concerned any changes made to a program that invokes undefined behaviour can have any result - there doesn't have to be a logic behind it. And in fact it is very seldom fruitful to try to reason about how a given implementation behaves when encountering undefined behaviour.

That said if a call to `printf` (or any other function) changes the behaviour of your program (beyond the obvious change of printing what it's supposed to, of course), one possible explanation is that you have an invalid pointer somewhere that points to a local variable that's out of scope. If that variable previously lived in the stack memory that's now used by `printf` for its own local variables, that means the memory that the pointer points to will now be overridden with a new value. And that can of course change the behaviour of any code that use the pointer.